# isNotificationOnly: true is not working in teams mobile app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notification-only) documentation. I don't want users to send messages. So I changed isNotificationOnly: true and it's working as expected on my PC. I am able to send messages to teams on the mobile app. So Do we need to make some additional changes in the manifest.json file?

```
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": true
    }
  ]
```

**More details:**

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

These are the bot-related packages added to my project.

**Edit**: It should show like this.

**My completed manifest.**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "packageName": "com.XXXX.teams.XXXXX.framework.XXXX",
  "developer": {
    "name": "XXXX",
    "websiteUrl": "https://XXXXX.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://XXXXX.com/company/legal/privacy-policy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://XXXXX.com/company/legal/privacy-policy"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "XXXXX Bot ",
    "full": "XXXXX Bot"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Provide interactive automation between end user and Neurons Bots.",
    "full": "The XXXX bot for Microsoft Teams provides interactive capabilities between the end user and Ivanti Neurons Bots. Administrators now can solicit real-time responses from their users during the execution of a Bots workflow and use that input to deliver a more tailored experience to their end user."
  },
  "accentColor": "#FF1515",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com"
  ],
  "configurableProperties": [
    "name",
    "shortDescription",
    "longDescription",
    "smallImageUrl",
    "largeImageUrl",
    "accentColor",
    "developerUrl",
    "privacyUrl",
    "termsOfUseUrl"
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: We are checking this, meanwhile in the attached bots part manifest has "isNotificationOnly": false. Could you please confirm you are using "isNotificationOnly": true only.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT its true. I have mentioned that in the question, But anyways I have changed the body as well. Please let me know IF you need more clarity

Comment: We checked this at our end, and it is working fine in mobile as well, we checked in Android and iOS. It is showing "conversation with this bot is not supported" message.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have added the screenshot, It should show like this on teams. Is it the same behaviour for your as well?

Comment: Could you please share your manifest file, I will compare it with mine. If there is something else I need to configure?

Comment: Attaching the manifest screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWS1I.png.

Teams Web Client - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C5Ij.png

Teams Android - https://i.stack.imgur.com/95bVy.jpg

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have added my completed manifest, If you could point out something in this? Or do you need some more information which could help you to reproduce or know the root cause?

Comment: We see that in the above manifest has "isNotificationOnly": false. We changed it to true and added fields like id, botId. We checked this in web and Android mobile. It is working fine. Could you please let us know if you are facing this in both Android & iOS? Also please make sure that your app package has "isNotificationOnly": true.

Web - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRCyK.png ,  Android - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oksDs.png

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT sorry for the typo. isNotificationOnly was true in my code. I have only tested in android.

Comment: Would it be possible to for you to share the demo tenant creds where this issue is reproducible? Please share creds at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.